# stop default from looping

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I was making a prayer times app and it consists of a basic switch statement and a class. I made a default which was an error, but the error keeps on looping since I have a while statement. How can I stop the loop right at the default, I want to loop the switch statement below is my code -

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();

while (true)
{
    switch (input)
    {
        case "6/12/2017":
        case "06/12/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:14 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:51 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:53 PM");               
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:27 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:10 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/13/2017":
        case "06/13/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:14 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:51 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:54 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:27 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:10 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/14/2017":
        case "06/14/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:14 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:51 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:54 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:28 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:11 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/15/2017":
        case "06/15/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:14 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:52 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:54 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:28 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:11 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/16/2017":
        case "06/16/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:14 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:52 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:55 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:28 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:12 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/17/2017":
        case "06/17/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:14 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:52 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:55 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:29 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:12 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/18/2017":
        case "06/18/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:15 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:52 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:55 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:29 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:13 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/19/2017":
        case "06/19/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:15 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:52 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:55 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:29 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:13 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/20/2017":
        case "06/20/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:15 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:53 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:55 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:30 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:13 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/21/2017":
        case "06/21/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:15 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:53 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:56 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:30 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:13 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/22/2017":
        case "06/22/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:33 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:15 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:53 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:56 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:30 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:14 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/23/2017":
        case "06/23/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:33 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:15 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:53 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:56 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:30 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:13 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/24/2017":
        case "06/24/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:33 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:16 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:52 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:56 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:30 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:14 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Error - Please make sure you're input is similar to the example shown");
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of `while (true)`, do `while (myBool)`. Then define `bool myBool = true;` somewhere before your `while`. In your `default` case, set `myBool = false;`. Now once the `default` case is hit the first time, your `while` loop will no longer be `true` and therefore it will exit.

Comment: Your code will keep running because you're setting the while loop to true. If you want a simple solution, change the `true` to a variable that's set to true, then later set that variable to `false`

Comment: You may want to consider parsing the input into a `DateTime`.  You should be able to avoid the switch statement that way and handle many more dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
While (true)
```

This is infinity loop. You must use variable to get this done.

But. I think that you want to get user's input while your default case being hit.

So your code should be something like this :

```
bool switchItWhenDone= true;
while (switchItWhenDone)
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    switch (input)
    {
        case "6/12/2017":
        case "06/12/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:14 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:51 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:53 PM");               
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:27 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:10 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/13/2017":
        case "06/13/2017":
        Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:14 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:51 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:54 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:27 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:10 PM");
        Console.WriteLine();
        break;

    case "6/14/2017":
    case "06/14/2017":
        Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:14 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:51 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:54 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:28 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:11 PM");
        Console.WriteLine();
        break;

    case "6/15/2017":
    case "06/15/2017":
        Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:14 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:52 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:54 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:28 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:11 PM");
        Console.WriteLine();
        break;

    case "6/16/2017":
    case "06/16/2017":
        Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:14 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:52 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:55 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:28 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:12 PM");
        Console.WriteLine();
        break;

    case "6/17/2017":
    case "06/17/2017":
        Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:14 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:52 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:55 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:29 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:12 PM");
        Console.WriteLine();
        break;

    case "6/18/2017":
    case "06/18/2017":
        Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:15 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:52 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:55 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:29 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:13 PM");
        Console.WriteLine();
        break;

    case "6/19/2017":
    case "06/19/2017":
        Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:15 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:52 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:55 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:29 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:13 PM");
        Console.WriteLine();
        break;

    case "6/20/2017":
    case "06/20/2017":
        Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:15 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:53 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:55 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:30 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:13 PM");
        Console.WriteLine();
        break;

    case "6/21/2017":
    case "06/21/2017":
        Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:15 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:53 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:56 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:30 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:13 PM");
        Console.WriteLine();
        break;

    case "6/22/2017":
    case "06/22/2017":
        Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:33 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:15 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:53 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:56 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:30 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:14 PM");
        Console.WriteLine();
        break;

    case "6/23/2017":
    case "06/23/2017":
        Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:33 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:15 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:53 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:56 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:30 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:13 PM");
        Console.WriteLine();
        break;

    case "6/24/2017":
    case "06/24/2017":
        Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:33 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:16 AM");
        Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:52 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:56 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:30 PM");
        Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:14 PM");
        Console.WriteLine();
        break;

    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Error - Please make sure you're input is similar to the example shown");
switchItWhenDone=false;
        break;
}
```

}

Comment: If once default case executed and than after any other case executed what will do ???

Comment: I understand that he wants to stop loop when default case is hit.

Answer (score 2):

You can set a `bool` to true once the default state is entered.

Example:

```
bool end = false;
while (!end)
{
    switch (input)
    {
        // Your switch code

        default:
            end= true;
            Console.WriteLine("Error - Please make sure you're input is similar to the example shown");
            break;

     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if i understand you correctly want to insert this line

```
 string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

into the while loop, that way every time the loop starts it will give the user an option to insert new input.

Comment: Now just combine my answer with this one and you'll be good to go!

Answer (score 1):

In your example you can easily replace the break with a return statement:

```
default:
    //...
    return;
```

Because the switch statement is the last one in your method. Otherwise I'd put the loop inside another method, where you can use the return statement again:

```
while (true)
{
    switch (input)
    {
        //...
        default:
            return;
//...
```

Otherwise there are two different, in my opinion not that recommendable solutions:

**1. Use a label with a goto**

However, nobody would suggest to do this. It would look like this:

```
while (true)
{
    switch (input)
    {
        //...
        default:
            //...
            goto after;
    }
}
after:
; //The semicolon is only needed when the label would be the last statement in the method otherwise, as it is in your example
```

**2. Use a variable**

You could replace your endless loop with a conditional loop:

```
var finished = false;
while (!finished)
{
    switch (input)
    {
        //...
        default:
            //...
            finished = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

This is a rather nice solution in that case as well.

By the way, your code has another problem, as you probably want to put the input assignment in your while loop. In total, I'd suggest something like this:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();

while (true)
{
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    switch (input)
    {
        case "6/12/2017":
        case "06/12/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:14 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:51 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:53 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:27 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:10 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/13/2017":
        case "06/13/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:14 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:51 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:54 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:27 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:10 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/14/2017":
        case "06/14/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:14 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:51 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:54 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:28 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:11 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/15/2017":
        case "06/15/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:14 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:52 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:54 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:28 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:11 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/16/2017":
        case "06/16/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:14 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:52 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:55 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:28 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:12 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/17/2017":
        case "06/17/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:14 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:52 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:55 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:29 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:12 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/18/2017":
        case "06/18/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:15 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:52 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:55 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:29 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:13 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/19/2017":
        case "06/19/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:15 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:52 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:55 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:29 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:13 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/20/2017":
        case "06/20/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:15 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:53 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:55 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:30 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:13 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/21/2017":
        case "06/21/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:32 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:15 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:53 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:56 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:30 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:13 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/22/2017":
        case "06/22/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:33 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:15 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:53 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:56 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:30 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:14 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/23/2017":
        case "06/23/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:33 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:15 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:53 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:56 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:30 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:13 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        case "6/24/2017":
        case "06/24/2017":
            Console.WriteLine("Fajr - 3:33 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Sunrise - 5:16 AM");
            Console.WriteLine("Dhuhr - 12:52 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Asr - 4:56 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Maghrib - 8:30 PM");
            Console.WriteLine("Isha - 10:14 PM");
            Console.WriteLine();
            break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Error - Please make sure you're input is similar to the example shown");
            return;
    }

}
```